# How to get asset location in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a js file in my laravel project and i have some links in it that points to some asset files. I am trying to locate this dynamically. How do i do this??

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('editor');
sceditor.create(textarea, {
    emoticons:{
    dropdown: {
        ':)': '../editor/emoticons/smile.png',
        ':angel:': '../editor/emoticons/angel.png',
        ':alien:': '../editor/emoticons/alien.png',
        ':blink:': '../editor/emoticons/blink.png',
        ':angry': '../editor/emoticons/angry.png',
        ':D': '../editor/emoticons/grin.png',
        ':P': '../editor/emoticons/tongue.png',
        ':blush:': '../editor/emoticons/blush.png',
        ':(': '../editor/emoticons/cwy.png',
        '<3': '../editor/emoticons/heart.png'
    }
},
    format: 'xhtml',
    icons: 'monocons',
    style: '../editor/minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
});
```

I have a folder in my public folder that contains all this but how do i locate them dynamically. I know if it is a normal blade file i can use `{{ asset('') }}` how do i do this in this js file?

Comment: First of all, use absolute paths because if you are using this script in a lot of places, you depend on `..` will always be the root URL, so always use `absolute` URLs.... Second, you don't do that if you know they are dynamic, you consume your own API and share all the emotes and their respective URLs... And lastly, what issue do you have? It is not clear what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I hope in laravel blade you can directly use blade syntax inside a javascript code like this try it out like this

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('editor');
sceditor.create(textarea, {
    emoticons:{
    dropdown: {
        ':)': '{{asset('editor/emoticons/smile.png') }} ',
    }
},
    format: 'xhtml',
    icons: 'monocons',
    style: '{{ asset(' editor/minified/themes/content/default.min.css') }} '
});
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: you cannot use blade inside a .js file

Answer (score 0):

In the `head` of your HTML (in a blade file), you can use `window.assetUrl = '{{asset('')}}';`. Then, in your JS files, you can call `':)': window.assetUrl + 'editor/emoticons/smile.png'`. This way your asset URL is dynamic (based on what the app URL is).